# FFmpeg split and concatenate issues

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFmpeg to split different clips, concatenate them, and then reencode the concatenated stream. Here is the command line that I would  like to use with 2 input clips (actually I would like to use more than 2, but 2 would suffice for illustrating this problem) as example:

```
./ffmpeg -y -noautorotate -ss 4.9 -i in0.ts -noautorotate -i in1.ts \
   -threads 0 -map_chapters -1 -write_tmcd 0 \
   -metadata location= -max_muxing_queue_size 2000 -f mp4 \
   -movflags faststart -filter_complex "[0:v:0]yadif=deint=interlaced,scale=1280:720:flags=bicubic,setdar=1.7777778[v0];[1:v:0]yadif=deint=interlaced,scale=1280:720:flags=bicubic,setdar=1.7777778[v1];[v0][0:a:0][v1][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[cat_v][cat_a]"
   -map "[cat_a]" -acodec aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -b:a 160k -async 1
   -sn -map "[cat_v]" -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 4 -b:v \
   5400k -preset medium -x264opts ref=3:keyint=90 \
   -r 30000/1001 -vsync 1 -metadata:s:v rotate= -pix_fmt yuv420p outputfile01.mp4
```

But the FFmpeg hangs and is stuck at frame 0. The `in0.ts` has its last key frame at 4s. If I were to change the `-ss 4.9` to `-ss X` where `X` <= 4.0, then there is no issue.

My FFmpeg version is 3.3. I am aware that this problem does not exist in FFmpeg 4.0.x onwards or in FFmpeg 3.2.x but exists in 3.3.x and 3.4.x. Can someone help me understand exactly what bug has been introduced in 3.3.x and 3.4.x that there is this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`-ss` before `-i` relies on seeking using the demuxer. For files with inter-coded video streams, the seek target will be a keyframe. The callback seek function in MPEG-TS demuxer returns the first keyframe after the specified point.

BTW, I can reproduce the effect with the latest builds. Why do you say the behaviour doesn't occur in 4.0 or 3.2?

---

To achieve the intended result, you can use the trim filters,

```
./ffmpeg -y -noautorotate -i in0.ts -noautorotate -i in1.ts -filter_complex "[0:v:0]yadif=deint=interlaced,trim=4.9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280:720:flags=bicubic,setdar=1.7777778[v0];[1:v:0]yadif=deint=interlaced,scale=1280:720:flags=bicubic,setdar=1.7777778[v1];[0:a:0]atrim=4.9,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[v0][a0][v1][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[cat_v][cat_a]" -sn -map "[cat_a]" -async 1 -ac 2 -ar 44100 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -map "[cat_v]" -r 30000/1001 -vsync 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -threads 0 -profile:v baseline -level:v 4 -b:v 5400k -preset medium -x264opts ref=3:keyint=90 -map_chapters -1 -metadata location= -metadata:s:v rotate= -max_muxing_queue_size 2000 -f mp4 -write_tmcd 0 -movflags faststart outputfile01.mp4
```

Comment: So, how does one get past this limitation? Is there a way to do what I would like to do by using -ss before -i at all for this case?